# Invalid Data in Hive-Created Table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez

I'm using Hive version 3.1.3 on Hadoop 3.3.4 with Tez 0.9.2. I'm trying to run a `SELECT` statement on table that Hive created and manages. The query never finishes and fails. The full error message is below, but this appears to be the relevant portion:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.LongColumnVector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.DecimalColumnVector
```

It looks like the error is a long to decimal conversion issue. However, this table was created by Hive, loading/transforming data in a previous step. Wouldn't Hive have thrown an error earlier if it was inserting an invalid value into a decimal column?

I used the exact same codebase and the exact same data on AWS EMR and didn't get this error, so I don't think there's an invalid value. But I'm stuck on where to go from here.

Here's the table definition:

```
claimid             varchar(50)
claimlineid         int
dos                 date
dosto               date
member              varchar(50)
provider            varchar(50)
setname             varchar(255)
code                varchar(50)
system              varchar(255)
primary             int
positivenegative    int
result              decimal(10,2)
supply              int
size                decimal(10,2)
quantity            decimal(10,2)
```

And here's the full error message:

```
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1667735849290_0030_32_15, diagnostics=[Task failed, taskId=task_1667735849290_0030_32_15_000009, diagnostics=[TaskAttempt 0 failed, info=[Error: Error while running task ( failure ) : attempt_1667735849290_0030_32_15_000009_0:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive Runtime Error while closing operators
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:296)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.run(TezProcessor.java:250)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.run(LogicalIOProcessorRuntimeTask.java:374)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:73)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable$1.run(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:61)
        at org.apache.tez.runtime.task.TaskRunner2Callable.callInternal(TaskRunner2Callable.java:37)
        at org.apache.tez.common.CallableWithNdc.call(CallableWithNdc.java:36)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:108)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:41)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:77)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Hive Runtime Error while closing operators
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.close(MapRecordProcessor.java:488)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezProcessor.initializeAndRunProcessor(TezProcessor.java:284)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
DeserializeRead detail: Reading byte[] of length 4096 at start offset 4 for length 100 to read 14 fields with types [varchar(50), int, date, date, varchar(50), varchar(50), varchar(255), varchar(50), varchar(255), int, decimal(10,2), int, decimal(10,2), decimal(10,2)].  Read field #14 at field start position 0 current read offset 104
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.closeOp(MapJoinOperator.java:611)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.mapjoin.VectorMapJoinGenerateResultOperator.closeOp(VectorMapJoinGenerateResultOperator.java:681)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:733)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator.close(Operator.java:757)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.MapRecordProcessor.close(MapRecordProcessor.java:477)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
DeserializeRead detail: Reading byte[] of length 4096 at start offset 4 for length 100 to read 14 fields with types [varchar(50), int, date, date, varchar(50), varchar(50), varchar(255), varchar(50), varchar(255), int, decimal(10,2), int, decimal(10,2), decimal(10,2)].  Read field #14 at field start position 0 current read offset 104
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.mapjoin.VectorMapJoinGenerateResultOperator.reProcessBigTable(VectorMapJoinGenerateResultOperator.java:609)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.continueProcess(MapJoinOperator.java:671)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapJoinOperator.closeOp(MapJoinOperator.java:604)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
DeserializeRead detail: Reading byte[] of length 4096 at start offset 4 for length 100 to read 14 fields with types [varchar(50), int, date, date, varchar(50), varchar(50), varchar(255), varchar(50), varchar(255), int, decimal(10,2), int, decimal(10,2), decimal(10,2)].  Read field #14 at field start position 0 current read offset 104
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.mapjoin.VectorMapJoinGenerateResultOperator.reProcessBigTable(VectorMapJoinGenerateResultOperator.java:589)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.LongColumnVector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.DecimalColumnVector
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorDeserializeRow.storePrimitiveRowColumn(VectorDeserializeRow.java:687)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorDeserializeRow.storeRowColumn(VectorDeserializeRow.java:934)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.VectorDeserializeRow.deserialize(VectorDeserializeRow.java:1360)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.vector.mapjoin.VectorMapJoinGenerateResultOperator.reProcessBigTable(VectorMapJoinGenerateResultOperator.java:585)
        ... 23 more
```

Comment: Hive uses "schema on read", so no, the error wouldn't happen when writing data.

Comment: According to the error, it wants your 14th field to be a DOUBLE or FLOAT, not DECIMAL (perhaps when you wrote it, it was truncated to remove the decimal)

Comment: [HIVE-23909](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-23909)? Can you disable vectorization (set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled=false) and try?

Comment: @mazaneicha thanks, I'll give that a try. I've shifted focus to migrating our workload to Spark since this is only the first of many insurmountable issues I've had with Hive/Hadoop/Tez. But I'll give that a shot once my Spark testing is complete.

Comment: Absolutely, just use Spark! No reason to suffer PITA of Hive+Tez if Spark is an option.

Comment: @mazaneicha yeah it's a shame, I used Hive for a few years back in 2012 at a large insurance company, and it was great. It's really sad how much of a second-class citizen Hive is now.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a problem with CBO. You can disable it, run the expression and get the result.
`set hive.cbo.enable=false;`